# How do I use request.js to send text as the request body?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to use the request.js library for Node to send a post request with plain text as the body, but I'm finding that the server I'm sending to is receiving an empty body, or perhaps a body consisting of an empty object (logging the body yields {}).
If I send it using Postman, it works properly, so it seems clear that the problem is with my usage of request.js.
The code of the relevant function (with the url changed) is as follows:

```
function (queryText) {
        const options = {
            url: "https://myurl.com/",
            body: queryText
        };
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            request.post(options, (err, response) => {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else resolve(response);
            });
        });
    }
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure `queryText` is not `undefined`?

Comment: Thank you, but I am sure; I even logged options.body and got exactly what I expected.

Comment: Also, I realized that the log is {}, so that might mean a body containing an empty object instead, so I updated it accordingly.  I also tested using a string literal instead and it still ended up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `content-type` header like so:

```
const options = {
    url: "https://myurl.com/",
    body: queryText,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'text/plain'
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't change anything; I still get {} as my request body on the other end.  I also would prefer to just get the body directly, as seems to be possible using Postman.

Comment: @user1837296 what technology are you using on the other end?

Comment: Another Node (express) script.  The relevant code is:   
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.body);
 app.pool.query(req.body)
  .then(pgres => res.status(200).send(pgres))
  .catch(err => res.status(500).send("Accesser error: " + err));
});

Comment: are you using the body-parser middleware?

Comment: On the back end, I am, specifically bodyParser.text(), and that works fine when sending via Postman.  On the front end (where I'm using the request library), I am not using it in that module, and the Express app used in another module (as the back end for other front ends) parses using bodyParser.json().

Comment: do mind trying this?

body: `JSON.stringify({data: queryText})` and accessing it on the server via the `data` property of the body?

Also could you just use `bodyParser.json()` for the other part too?

Comment: @user1837296 I think I found a solution for you, just try adding `headers: {
        'content-type': 'text/plain'
      }` to the `options` constant in your code

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.  I don't really want to accept and upvote a wrong answer that has the right answer in its comments, so can you please post that answer separately so that I can accept and upvote it?